# Super+Space not working on Unity 17.10

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 17.10, keyboard-layout

Until 17.10 I mostly used Unity and never had this issue (I had GNOME installed and seldom used it). But since the upgrade I switched to GNOME, where the shortcut works and I find it better because it cycles through sources in the recently used order.

After a few months I decided to reinstall Ubuntu because it was too laggy, so the Unity session I have now was installed manually later. Then I noticed that it was GNOME especially that was too laggy on my 4GB RAM laptop, so I moved back to Unity which is much more fluid.

Here comes the issue, pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't switch the input sources, and the weirdest thing is that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows and horizontal switcher for English and French, instead of the vertical drop-down switcher from the panel where I don't even have an English source (I have French, Japanese and Belgian sources).

**Note :**
I noticed that other shortcuts that use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key don't work as well as the other shortcuts : i.e. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> which I set to open nautilus as root only works when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd> then release <kbd>E</kbd> and finally release <kbd>Super</kbd>. I don't remember having a 'release order' before, could it be related to the issue ?

**Note 2 :**
I know I can bind another shortcut for this task (and it works), but I find the default one pretty good and I don't like this <kbd>Super</kbd> key malfunction.

**UPDATE**

About the input sources showed when I do  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (English and French), I found that they are the same as in *Fcitx Configuration* (which key binding is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and as in *IBus Preferences* (which key binding was also set to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but I set it to something else to test, however <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> still does not work).

Comment: Please show what the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source` outputs.

Comment: Show us also what the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` outputs.

Comment: It outputs `['<Super>space']`  (as expected I suppose)

Comment: Yes, it was expected. What about the other command I suggested?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`? Does Alt+Shift switch keyboard layout?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson here is what gives the second command `[('xkb', 'fr'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp'), ('xkb', 'be+wang')]`
@N0rbert your command outputs this : 
`XKBLAYOUT=fr,be
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=,wang`

Comment: Everything looks normal AFAICT. Maybe it's a hardware issue. As a workaround, and as @N0rbert indicated, you may want to install `gnome-tweak-tool` and use Tweak to set an alternative shortcut for switching input sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The shortcut was bound to something else** and the other actions bound to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> were not executed.

I was wondering why `sushi` wasn't working on nautilus when I noticed that what I wanted was `gnome-sushi`, so I uninstalled (and purged) `sushi` and now <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> allow me to switch between the IBus input sources.

As the IBus input sources are not the same as the ones I setted through the System Settings, I changed IBus key binding (can be done by typing `ibus-setup` in terminal).

I still don't know why the IBus (and the fcitx) input sources aren't the same as the ones in System Settings, but my problem is solved.

**EDIT :** I had this issue again, so it might not have been sushi (but maybe it was sushi first, and something else after that), but I have [found a work-around](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997254/unity-input-language-switch-keys-not-working) which is to switch back to lightdm (which is fine to me since it is more continuous than gdm with Unity).

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 17.10 solution:

1. Run `ibus-setup`
2. Disable shortcut for changing layouts (delete it).
3. Set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut in System Settings -> Keyboard.

It's a conflict between IBus and System Settings shortcuts.

Comment: No, as I said I changed it to something else and Super+Space still doesn't work (and if it was bound to IBus, I would see it since there is a "visual feedback" when switching IBus sources)

Comment: Works for me, but with annoying delay((

Comment: This works but it's still interfering with the Unity plugin - while changing input sources, the Dash menu or keyboard shortcuts popup occasionally display. I used ccsm to disable the Unity plugin's Super shortcut, which works around the issue, as I rarely use the dash.