# Unity input language switch keys not working

Tags: unity, 17.10, input-language

In Ubuntu 17.10 when I switch to Unity desktop I cannot switch the input language using keyboard, however when I log in in Gnome everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I switched my display manager from lightdm to gdm (using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`). But now I am facing another problem in Unity: I cannot switch to another user.